# get frame from binary data with python

Tags: python, binary-data, video-thumbnails

I have **Binary string** of mp4 file (from database).

I'd Like to get frame (thumbnail) of video from this string and save as binary string (in database).

Is there library, that would have method that takes **binary data** as an input, **not file name**

Or maybe there is a way to save binary data as buffer or something and work with that as file, without saving it on hard drive or server..

Comment: Have you tried to find any libraries yourself? If so which of them have you tried and did you bump into any issues that we could solve with those libraries?

Comment: I have tried [openCV] (http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), but It take file name as input, not binary string. At least I was not able to find the way to do it, in documentation

Comment: Good, now combine that with [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and you're all set.

Comment: @Torxed could you please help further.

I'm tying something like this:
`import io
import cv2

b = io.BytesIO('AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAW1wN')  #
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(b)
`
I'm missing something.

Comment: Sure, if you give me some code that sorta works but you're having problems with. As of now I'd be starting your project all the way from the start if I even considered helping further. I solved your opencv issue but this is still a "help me find a library" question and is not generally allowed on SO.

Comment: Yes, seeing as this question in particular isn't about a specific programming issue. It's a direct question to find a tool or library. Gotta give it tho, from the comments you solved one problem by starting to use `BytesIO`, but again. This question should be closed. Once you've played around with `BytesIO` and you think you're on to something open a new question and make sure it's related to a specific programming issue and paste some code example that the people here at SO can work with. That's the key, show us some code and we'd gladly help.

Comment: @IrakliMchedlishvili did you figure out how to do it? I don't think it is as straightforward as just using BytesIO. If you take a look at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp, it only takes a device or a filename as the input. I think the only way would be to write it to a file and read it again?

Comment: @leet this was 3 ago but as much as I remember I was getting the wrong string before passing it cv2. Meaning BytesIO and cv2 combination should work